# Writing variables to new line of txt file in python

Tags: python, string, file, variables, append

From other posts, I've learned that '\n' signifies a new line when adding to a txt file. I'm trying to do just this, but I can't figure out the right syntax when an attribute is right before the new line.

My code I'm trying is like this:

```
for item in list:
    with open("file.txt", "w") as att_file:
        att_file.write(variable\n)
```

As you can probably see, I'm trying to add the variable for each item in the list to a new line in a txt file. What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to specify the newline character as a string:

Eg:

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as att_file:
    for item in list:
        att_file.write(attribute + "\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
att_file.write(attribute+"\n")
```

## note :attribute must be some variable and must be string type

your code will look like this:

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as att_file:
    for item in list:
        att_file.write(item+"\n")
```

`with` should be before `for`, else every time you are opening file with write mode, it will omit the 
previous write

Comment: Thanks for telling me about the possible issue with "with" and "for", that is definitely good to know.

Answer (score 0):

file7 = open('test_list7_file.txt','a')

file7.write(var7 + '\n')

will work fine, **BUT IF YOU APPEND TO EXISTING** txt file the MOUSE CURSOR
needs to be **ONE SPACE AFTER THE LAST ENTRY** when you save the file for use in your program.

~no space and it joins the last entry,

~on the next line already when you create you file to be added to, it adds an empty line first